# How to add a custom filter to Jinja2 and bundle in Sceptre project?

Tags: python, jinja2, sceptre

I would like to add a filter like the [Ansible ipaddr filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html) to a [Cloudreach Sceptre](https://sceptre.cloudreach.com/latest/) project with Jinja2 templates. I'm not proficient with Python but I've seen the [Jinja2 documentation on adding custom filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#writing-filters), but this does not demystify for me how to add one so that it can be used in a Sceptre project, and bundled with it.

If I would like to add custom filters to my Sceptre project that can be packaged with my templates (in the local project directory) and hook into the Jinja2 `environment.filters[]` registration process through Sceptre, how might I go about it? Assume a sceptre project structure as follows:

```
sceptre_project/
    config/
    filters/
        custom_filter.py
    templates/
```